How can I close a MoviePy Window that opens after clip.preview in e tkinter GUI?
I am developing a GUI application using Tkinter, where the user can click a button to start playing a video. I am using MoviePy to ensure that the video and audio play synchronously, but the issue I am facing is that the video opens in a separate window. This window does not close after the video ends, which prevents the user from interacting with the main GUI.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import tkinter as tk
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

root = tk.Tk()
root.title()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

# Function to play the video
def play_video():
    clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)  # Replace with your video path
    clip.preview()

play_button = tk.Button(root, text="Play", command=play_video)
play_button.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

root.mainloop()

Current Issue:

When the user clicks the "Play" button, the video plays in a new
window. This window stays open after the video ends, preventing
further interaction with the main GUI.

Goal:
I want to ensure that after the video is played, users can continue working in the GUI. This might be achieved in one of the following ways:

Play the video (including synchronized audio) directly within the
Tkinter main window.
If the video must open in a separate window, have that window close
automatically after the video is finished.
If neither of the above is possible, provide a seamless transition
back to the main GUI.

Background:

I chose MoviePy to ensure audio synchronization, as I experienced
issues with other libraries in the past (e.g. tkVideoPlayer, pygame, bvPlayer).
My implementation is in Python 3.8.

I appreciate any help or suggestions!

The preview() function does not include parameters to change this behavior.
However, MoviePy uses PyGame internally, so it is possible to close the window once a video has finished using pygame.quit():
import tkinter as tk
import pygame
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

root = tk.Tk()
root.title()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

# Function to play the video
def play_video():
    clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)  # Replace with your video path
    clip.preview()
    pygame.quit()

play_button = tk.Button(root, text="Play", command=play_video)
play_button.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

root.mainloop()


this works perfect, thanks!
